# Confusion regarding docuents to send to ACS for skill assessment

Tags: australia

This is like my first post in here .

So I am planning to send my documents to ACS for skills assessment and I am a bit confused regarding the kind of documents that I should send them.

Before going into the types of documents that I am going to send them , I would like to give a brief overview of the education system in Nepal.
In Nepal , after completing grade 10 we appear for School Leaving Certificate (S.L.C.) examinations . Upon completing the exams we get a S.L.C marksheet and a character certificate. After grade 10, we normally join a college to complete grade 11 and 12 . After completing grade 12 we get a combined transcript of grade 11 and 12 and also a character certificate (one character certificate for both grade 11 and 12 ). Then in bachelors aswell we get one transcript and a character certificates. Besides these we also get various other certificates.

And I have worked in three companies as a software engineer.

Now I would like to list the documents that I am planning to send over to ACS

1. S.L.C. : character certificate and marksheet
2. 11 and 12 :character certificate and marksheet
3. Bachelors : character certificate , transcript and certificate indicating the completion of my bachelors that I received in my convocation.
4. My experience letter of Company a
5. My experience letter of Company b
6. My experience letter of Company c.

As per my understanding my documents are of 6 episodes (I am not totally sure) . Is that so ? Also will these documents be enough or do I need to send more documents?

Similarly the next question that I have is can I file one application stating that I want 189 and 190 visa?

Also for 190 is Victoria or NSW good? (As I am a software engineer , I would like to go to such states which has good opportunites for me to work )
Any suggestions

Answer (score 5):

For ACS, all you need is:

- Bachelors (or higher) qualification documents relevant to your nominated occupation. So, 10'th, 12'th, character, etc are not required. As for the education documents - you will need transcripts (marksheets) and degree passing certificate (which shows the date you completed the degree).
- Your passport.
- Employment documents: Reference letters from employers with details of your skills to prove that you possess the skills required for the nominated occupation. If not from your employers, you can ask your managers/ supervisors to state these for you in notarised statutory declarations. In case of statutory declarations, you will need to submit either the employment contract, service certificate, or 2 payslips on the employers' letterheads. ANZSCO-Descriptions-2015.pdf and Skills-Assessment-Guidelines-for-Applicants.pdf from the ACS website has more details about these.

Your skills assessment is not tied to 189, 190, 489, etc. With this (and English proficiency test results) you would be eligible to apply for an Expression of Interest (EOI) in the SkillSelect system and you can choose either 189, 190, 489, or all of these options in the same EOI.